# Extend Accestoken LifeTime Azure AD Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Hello I want to extend the Access Token lifetime of my Azure App registration.
I understand that there were a lot of SO questions already but none of them seem to work so instead answering on each one of them with my question, I guessed I create a new question.

I use the following PowerShell code to create an Azure AD Policy to extend the lifetime and attach it to my app registration.

```
  # import the azure ad module
Import-Module AzureADPreview

# connect with an admin with proper priviledges
Connect-AzureAD

# specify the policyname and Azure application name

$policyName = "ExtendedLifeTimePolicyADAppRegistration"
$applicationName = "AzureTest"


Write-Host "Create a new policy"
$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"04:00:00","MaxInactiveTime":"04:00:00","MaxAgeMultiFactor":"04:00:00","MaxAgeSingleFactor":"04:00:00"}}') -DisplayName $policyName -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"

# Get the Azure AD application  
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq '$applicationName'"
Write-Host "Apply the new policy"
Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy -Id $app.ObjectId -RefObjectId $policy.Id

Write-Host "Get assigned policies..."
Get-AzureADApplicationPolicy -Id $app.ObjectId
```

No error code has been shown and the Get-AzureADApplicationPolicy returned that the policy is connected to my azure ad application.

The following Code prints the access token and the expiry:
I used this code to print out the access token from the Azure AD app registration.

```
disconnect-azurermaccount
 if(-not (Get-Module AzureRm.Profile)) {
    Import-Module AzureRm.Profile
  }

function Get-AzureRmCachedAccessToken()
{
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

    if(-not (Get-Module AzureRm.Profile)) {
        Import-Module AzureRm.Profile
    }
    $azureRmProfileModuleVersion = (Get-Module AzureRm.Profile).Version
    # refactoring performed in AzureRm.Profile v3.0 or later
    if($azureRmProfileModuleVersion.Major -ge 3) {
        $azureRmProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
        if(-not $azureRmProfile.Accounts.Count) {
            Write-Error "Ensure you have logged in before calling this function."    
        }
    } else {
        # AzureRm.Profile < v3.0
        $azureRmProfile = [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
        if(-not $azureRmProfile.Context.Account.Count) {
            Write-Error "Ensure you have logged in before calling this function."    
        }
    }

    $currentAzureContext = Get-AzureRmContext
    $currentAzureContext
    $profileClient = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient($azureRmProfile)
    Write-Debug ("Getting access token for tenant" + $currentAzureContext.Tenant.TenantId)
    $currentAzureContext.TokenCache.ReadItems()
    $token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($currentAzureContext.Tenant.TenantId)
   echo "####"
    $token

     echo "####"
}
$tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$ClientID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"


    $passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $ClientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
    $pscredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ClientId, $passwd)


    #Connect-AzurermAccount -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $tenantId 
    Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $pscredential -TenantId $tenantId  -ServicePrincipal
    Get-AzureRmCachedAccessToken
```

First I thought my code to capture the access token is not valid enough because it is cached so I tried the following code from the MS doc following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token) in postman. But this has the same output as the previous PowerShell code. which is the same default Expiry of 1 hour.

In previous SO questions I've seen that people who changed the IsOrganizationDefault variable to "true" did get the AD policy working. 
Two remarks on this:

1. I do not have the right access to set this value on true because this impacts the entire tenant.
2. I do not want to set this on true. because this will also impact any other user who creates an App registration and retrieve an access token.

Does anyone see what I am missing, what I forget to do or what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, it just works with the `-IsOrganizationDefault $true` currently, no matter use `Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy` or `Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy`, if `-IsOrganizationDefault $false`, both not work.

You should note the feature [Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) is in preview, also the powershell commands you used are just in `AzureADPreview`. I believe the feature may have not been implemented completely, so it caused the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I am aware that it is a preview function but if it only works with the option "isorganizationdefault $true'. What is the point of the command Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy or AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy. The IsOrganizationDefault  will set the policy on the entire organisation.

Comment: @achahbar I think the feature has not been implemented, Microsoft should implement it in the future.